# Apache ErrorDocument: showing 404 URL

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, errordocument

I suspect this can't be done, but here goes anyway. Is there a way, on a *static* site, to show the URL the user is trying to reach when you use the Apache directive [ErrorDocument](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument) to redirect a 404 File Not Found error to a custom page? For instance, if you try:

```
http://www.fredriley.org.uk/dingbat/arsebiscuits
```

the default 404 error says:

```
The requested URL /dingbat/arsebiscuits was not found on this server.
```

So the URL must be in an environment variable. Can I get at that in a custom error document? I'd like to tell users the URL rather than just give them a generic error document. I know I can do this easily enough in PHP, but the site comprises static HTML docs only.

Comment: Having a static site does not prevent you from having a dynamic error page. Does your hosting service offer some kind of server-side technology?

Comment: Thanks, Álvaro. PHP is fine on the hosting service (Titan), so I suppose that I could write a PHP script for the 404. Probably REQUEST_URI (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) would be the best environment variable to use unless you could suggest a better approach?

Although the site (http://www.fredriley.org.uk/callhull) is primarily comprised of static docs I do use a couple of PHP scripts on it for forms so it would be no big to write another. I'm curious, though, if there's a way to access env vars in a static HTML doc.

Comment: Static means that: static ;-) I've written a proper answer for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Having a static site does not prevent you from having a dynamic error page. You can use whatever server-side technology your hosting service offers.

If you can use PHP, you can simply pick a static template, change its extension to `*.php` and add a little dynamic snippet:

```
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?></p>
```

If you can use [SSI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html), it's very similar:

```
<p><!--#echo var="REQUEST_URI" --></span></p>
```

The `REQUEST_URI` variable contains the local part of the URL as typed by the user (except hash). It's a good choice.

Comment: Thanks. I'd completely forgotten about SSI, it being relatively rare these days and unsupported by many hosts.